# Sublime Text 3 - adding newer CSS properties to the syntax highlighting list

Tags: css, properties, sublimetext, sublimetext4

as you can see from the picture the newer property aspect-ratio are not recognized, as with a ton of other new properties. Where can I add these new properties?

ryboe made a package to fix this, but it only works on separate css-file, not the `<script>`-tag.

[image]

Comment: What build number (**`Help → About Sublime Text`**) are you using? All these properties show up in the latest builds of ST4 (4143+).

Comment: @MattDMo Im using 4143, and for me some properties still dont show up.  `aspect-ratio` is even marked red...

Comment: @Adeerlike Do you have any CSS-related plugins or syntax definitions installed? I just downloaded a fresh portable version of 4143 and opened it in [safe mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html), so no plugins or extra packages or anything. I opened a blank HTML file, hit `<html` then Tab to create a template, put a `<style>` element in the `<head>`, and filled in the code from the question, adding a nonsense line at the bottom. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI2Si.png) is the result. All the properties were in the autocomplete dropdown, and all are recognized (italics) [...]

Comment: [...] except the last line, which is obviously not a real property. I don't know what else to suggest, except that you must have an interfering plugin. Try safe mode. I copied the code to a separate CSS file and it looked exactly the same.

Comment: Hmm, so in ST4 you can't even distinguish fake properties? That's maybe even worse...
I actually bought ST3, guess I felt pro... Hate that they just change the version number and cut me off until I buy it again!

Comment: @MattDMo  It was the SCSS styling package!  Do I have too many packages.. =\